# Fscanf on C code

Tags: c

I have to write C Code that reads some int numbers of a .txt file (in my case `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8` 9) and organise them on a int array. Then you have to declare three functions that return the maximum number, the minimum and the average of the numbers. In this case the results have to be `9`,`1` and `5`.
Why is this not doing the things I want? Apprecciate some help and sorry for my english.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Maximum(int array[]){
    int maximo=0, i;
    for(i=0;array[i]!=0;i++){
        if(array[i]>maximo){
            maximo=array[i];
        }
    }
    return(maximo);
}

int Minimum(int array[]){
    int minimo=0, i;
    for(i=0;array[i]!=0;i++){
        if(array[i]>minimo){
            minimo=array[i];
        }
    }
    return(minimo);
}

int Average(int array[]){
   float average;
   int i, suma=0;
   for(i=0;array[i]!=0;i++){
       suma+=array[i];
   }
   average=suma/i;
   return(average);
}



int main(void) { 
    int i, max, min;
    float med;
    int number[100];
    FILE *idf; 
    idf=fopen("Exercise_1.txt", "rt");
    if (idf==NULL)
        printf("ERROR openning file...");
    else {
        for(i=0;number[i]!='\0';i++){
            if(number[i]!=' '){
                fscanf(idf,"%d",&number[i]);                
            }
        }        
    }
    int fclose (FILE* idf);

    max=Maximum(number);
    min=Minimum(number);
    med=Average(number);

    printf("Max number: %d", max);
    printf("\nMin number: %d", min);
    printf("\nAverage: %f", med);

    return 0;
}
```

After doing this I get incredibly high numbers.

Comment: don't make `return` look like a function.

Comment: `int fclose (FILE* idf);`???

Comment: @SouravGhosh what do you mean?

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out what's actually in that array. `fscanf` doesn't work like that.

Comment: There are 2 bugs in your Average() function

Comment: The very _first_ time `for(i=0;number[i]!='\0';i++){` is executed, `number[0]` has never been set to anything, so how can code expect that compare to work?  It could be equal, it could be not equal, it could quite the program.

Comment: @chux How I translate that into c code?

Comment: Do not compare `number[i]` to anything until _after_ it has been assigned.  Assign first, then compare.

Comment: Since the list _must_ end is a 0, make a loop, iterative up to 99 times: (read number, verify read was successful, if 0, quit loop).  Set last `number[i]` to 0, call functions.

Comment: @chux How I read the numbers of the file then?

Comment: `if (fscanf(idf,"%d",&number[i]) == 1) Success() else Failure();`

Comment: [fix code sample](http://ideone.com/KVMmiU)

Comment: @BLUEPIXI `for(i=0; i < 100-1 && 1==fscanf(idf,"%d", &number[i]) && number[i] > 0;i++)` and if a `0` appears on the numbers of the file? What happens?

Comment: `0` can not be included in the data because it is used to mark the end of data.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY So how I include it?

Comment: The array and number of data pass to the function.

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("ERROR openning file...");` after the posted code reports a file open problem, it exits the if/else block and continues to printf info, etc including calling `fclose()` on the file.  However, the file was never open, so this will result in a problem (that can lead to undefined behaviour and a seg fault event.)  Suggest: after reporting the problem using `printf()` (I would have used `perror()` because that outputs to stderr and outputs both the enclosed text and the related system error message)  then the code should call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 0):

this part of the posted code:

```
if (idf==NULL)
    printf("ERROR openning file...");
else {
    for(i=0;number[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(number[i]!=' '){
            fscanf(idf,"%d",&number[i]);                
        }
    }        
}
```

contains a few problems

```
1) it will exit the loop early 
   if some un-initialized value in the `number[100]` array 
      happens to be all 0x00
2) it does not pay attention to the returned value from `fscanf()` 
   so does not know when EOF is reached or an I/O error occurs.
3) it does not set a final entry in the `numbers[100]` array 
   to the termination flag `0` 
   BTW: poor method for indicating last entry in array
        Suggest using the variable 'i' and passing 'i' to each
        of the sub functions
4) it keeps executing when the `fopen()` function 
   returned a failure condition
```

Suggest writing it like so:

```
// always place literal on left so compiler can catch `=` 
//   when should be `==` errors
if( NULL == idf )
{ // then fopen failed
    perror( "fopen for Exercise_1.txt for read failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fopen successful

// pre-init array to all 0 - this is a problem if input contains a 0
memset( number, 0x00, sizeof( number ) );

// input numbers into array until EOF or I/O error
for( i=0; 1==fscanf( idf, "%d", &number[i] ); i++ ) {;}
```

Comment: the posted answer will have a problem if the input file contains more that 99 entries.  So would be a good (and easy to do) idea to add a check in the `for()` loop.  I.E. `for( i=0; i<100, 1==fscanf( idf, "%d", &number[i] ); i++ ) {;}`